# How do I find the inverse of $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

$f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}$.  How do you find $f^{-1}$?

Is try and solve for y and I get the following:

$y = \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}$

$y(x^2 + 1) = x$

$yx^2 + y = x$

$y = -yx^2 + x$

$y = x(-yx + 1)$

It seems whatever I do I can't isolate the x variable, I just go in circles...

Comment: You have obtained a quadratic equation in $x$. Solve it for $x$.

Comment: Begin by the domain of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Ok, say the domain is restricted on the original function from -1 to 1.  Then the domain on the inverse of the function would be from -1/2 to 1/2.  The algebra would from the equations above would still be the same....correct?

Comment: So from the equations above...

Comment: Are you sure that the function is invertible? I think that, for any value of $y\in(-1/2,1/2)$ we have two values of $x$ such that y=f(x)$

Comment: @EmilioNovati That I'm positive of.  Putting x values in from [-1, 1] gives y values back from [-.5, .5]

Comment: @dxiv I don't understand.  If I solve the quadratic equation for x then I just get f(x) values...correct?  Just like I would if I was solving the polynomial $4x^2 + 2x + 5 = 0$.  For the inverse of the function don't I need to solve the formula in terms of y?

Comment: You've got it backwards. You know $y=f(x)$ and need to find the inverse $x=f^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: $f$ is an odd function.

Comment: @EmilioNovati So if the original function is $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}$ which is one-to-one over the interval [-1,1] with a range of [-1/2, 1/2].  Wouldn't the inverse of the function be one-to-one and therefore valid?

Comment: Yes, In the domain $[-1,1]$ the function is one -to-one, so it is invertible, and the inverse is $f^{-1}:[-1/2,1/2] \to [-1,1], f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{2x}$

Comment: See also: [How do you work out the inverse of functions such as $ f(x)= \frac{x}{ x^2-1} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2610927)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving for $x$ the equation
$$
yx^2-x+y=0
$$
we find
$$
x=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}
$$

this means that the range of the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ is the interval $(-1/2,1/2)$ and  the function is not invertible because for any value of $y$ in this interval we have two corresponding values of $x$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: $f^{-1}:[-1/2,1/2] \to [-1,1], f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{2x}$ is one to one.

Comment: @IdleMathGuy. Yes, see my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have easily (*solving a quadratic equation*)  for all $a$ such that $0\lt a\lt \frac 12$, the equality
$$f\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4a^2}}{2a}\right)=f\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4a^2}}{2a}\right)=a$$ This shows that $f$ is not injective so not bijective and has no inverse.

Comment: $f^{-1}:[-1/2,1/2] \to [-1,1], f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{2x}$ is injective.

Comment: $f$ is not injective.

Comment: See Emilio's comments and look at the graph.  Just by a simple horizontal line test you can see that f is injective over [-1/2, 1/2].