# How do you work out the inverse of functions such as $ f(x)= \frac{x}{ x^2-1} $?

Tags: calculus, functions

how do you find the inverse of a function such as:

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2-1} , x \in (-1,1)$$

Comment: You solve for $x$ the equation $x =y(x^2 -1)$ which is a classic quadratic equation. Then take care of the solution to consider since you will get two.

Comment: See also: [How do I find the inverse of $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1981806)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to find the inverse of $f(x)$, one solves $x = f(y)$ for $y$. In your case that yields
$$
x = \frac{y}{y^2-1} \Leftrightarrow xy^2 -y - x = 0
$$
for which you can apply the quadratic formula
$$
y_\pm = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-4x^2}}{2x}
$$
So there are 2 inverse functions.

Comment: No, there aren't. A function cannot have two inverses.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to solve the equation $\frac x{x^2-1}=a$ and to find a solution in $(-1,1)$.